# Extending Angular component with directive

Tags: angular

I wrote a directive which is adding a HostListener (in this case "focus") on any component. The directive should call a method on it's host component whenever the element is on focus.

```
<my-component myDirective>
    <h3>Hello World</h3>
</my-component>

<my-other-component myDirective>
    <button>Hello</button>
</my-other-component>
```

The HostListener inside myDirective

```
@HostListener('focus')
onFocus() {
    this.myService.myStream$
        .pipe(first())
        .subscribe((value => {
            this.myHostComponent.doSomeMagic(value);
        }))
}
```

Since it should work on every component i prefer to only implement the `doSomeMagic()` method in the components and letting the myDirective doing the work with the HostListener and the observable.

Is there a way to call a method on the directives host without knowing which component it actualy is?

Comment: [Here is a full github thread explaining it](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8277).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is [already answered on github](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8277)

Comment: why not, in your directive, call a function in your service that emit a value? then, subscribe to the service in your component (I hope this has any sense)

Answer (score 1):

I would do it with @Output and emit something like this:

```
@Directive({ selector: '[myFocusDirective]' })
export class FocusDirective {
@Output() myFocusDirective = new EventEmitter<MouseEvent>(); 

constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {}

@HostListener('focus')
onFocus() {
    this.myService.myStream$
        .pipe(first())
        .subscribe((value => {
            this.myFocusDirective.emit(value);;
        }))
}
```

and then to component

```
<input (myFocusDirective)="openDropdown()" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with an injected component:

Something like this should work, directive.ts:

`constructor(private myHostComponent: MyComponent) {}`

...

`this.myHostComponent.doSomeMagic(value);`

You will have to know the type of component tho.

I believe it could work if you would make and abstract component from which all your `doSomeMagic()` components will extend:

`constructor(private myHostComponent: MyAbstractComponent) {}`

`class MyAbstractComponent() {
    abstract doSomeMagic();
}`

I'm not sure about the abstract part, you will need to check if it works.

Edit:

You can also pass the reference to the component/element via directive input. Here is a quick StackBlitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-anhhhc?file=app/directive.ts